# Benefits of starting arrays at 0?

Tags: math, language-agnostic, computer-science

What's the purpose of array indices starting at `0` in most programming languages, in contrast to the ordinal way in which we refer to most things IRL (first, second, third, etc.)?  What's the logic or utility behind that?

I'm completely used to it by now, but never stopped to think about the reason behind it.

**Update**: One benefit I read about from Googling is that for loops can have `i < n` if you want to go up to `n`.

Comment: Because this is the *natural*  order. Both Church numerals and Peano axioms introduces zero as the first number in the sequence. Starting counting from 1 is counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dijkstra lays out the reasoning in [Why numbering should start at zero](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html).

> When dealing with a sequence of length N, the elements of which we wish to distinguish by subscript, the next vexing question is what subscript value to assign to its starting element...
>
> when starting with subscript 1, the subscript range 1 ≤ i < N+1; starting with 0, however, gives the nicer range 0 ≤  i < N. So let us let our ordinals start at zero: an element's ordinal (subscript) equals the number of elements preceding it in the sequence. And the moral of the story is that we had better regard —after all those centuries!— zero as a most natural number.

Comment: Though I wish I had a dollar for every `for` loop I've seen of the form: `for(i=0; i<=N; i++)`.

Comment: @sarnold If your job is fixing bugs in software, you probably do have a dollar for every one of those you've seen.  ;)

Comment: I want to state here, for the record, that I hate Edsger Dijkstra.

Answer (score 3):

When we're accessing item by index like a[i] the compiler converts it to [a+i]. So the index of first element is zero because [a+0] will give us 'a' that points to the first item in array. This is quite obviously for, say, C++ but not for more recent languages such as C#.

Answer (score 2):

Dijkstra wrote a really interesting paper about this, in 1982: [Why numbering should start at zero](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html).

Answer (score 1):

You may google for it, there's been a lot of discussions about it. I'd say that the fact that the offset of the first element from the beginning (which it is) is zero certainly makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Because [Dijkstra said so](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd08xx/EWD831.PDF).

Answer (score 1):

In my old assembler days it was natural for the offset to start at zero.

```
dcl   foo(9)
ldx0  0 'offset to index register 0

lda   foo,x0 'get first element
adx0  1,du   'get 2nd
ldq   foo,x0
```

When looking at it from the perspective of the hardware it makes more sense.